# Flow control constructs in C++, how to modify?

Tags: c++, loops, if-statement, for-loop

Here is the segment of codes. I want to go back to Loop 1, if the if-statement is successful. I need the program not to add a 1000, if the if-statement succeeds.

`editA.i` == 0  in the beginning of the program.

I want to compare two columns of strings and get the distance measure.

I've tried break and continue commands, but none of them is working as I want.

Thank You

```
for(editA.i; editA.i<6; editA.i++)  // Loop 1
{
    for(editB.j=0; editB.j<6; editB.j++)    // Loop 2
    {
        if(editA.A[editA.i] == editB.B[editB.j])  // if this statment works, 
            // I want to go back to "Loop 1". How???

            sum+= abs(editA.i - editB.j);

        else
            sum+= 1000;
    }

}
```

Comment: Show us how you used the `break` and how it didn't work. `break` is what you need here if you want to go from inside the inner loop to continuing on with the outer loop.

Comment: Please do not misuse the caps lock button. Especially in titles.

Comment: I have a feeling he tried to use break, but didn't have the curly-braces around the if-statement and it created an error.  Otherwise a break statement would have worked perfectly for what he wants.

Comment: #include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;


struct wordsA {
 string A[6];
 int i; 
 
};


struct wordsB {
  
 string B[6];
 int j;

 
};

 
void main()
{
  wordsA editA;
  wordsB editB;
  
  //Document Profile
  editA.A[0] = "TH";
  editA.A[1] = "ING";
  editA.A[2] = "ON";
  editA.A[3] = "ER";
  editA.A[4] = "AND";
  editA.A[5] = "ED";

  //Category Profile
  editB.B[0] = "TH";
  editB.B[1] = "ER";
  editB.B[2] = "ON";
  editB.B[3] = "LE";
  editB.B[4] = "ING";
  editB.B[5] = "AND";

Comment: editA.i = 0;
  editB.j = 0;

  int sum=0;

  for(int k=0; k<6; k++)
  {
   cout<<editA.A[k]<<" "<<k<<" "<<editB.B[k]<<endl;
  }

  cout<<endl;

  for(editA.i; editA.i<6; editA.i++)
  {
   for(editB.j=0; editB.j<6; editB.j++)
   {
    if(editA.A[editA.i] == editB.B[editB.j])
    {
     sum+= abs(editA.i - editB.j);
     break;
     
    }
    else
     sum+= 1000;
   }
  }

  cout<<"Distance Measure: "<<sum<<endl;
  
  
  
  system("pause");
}

Comment: @sermetCakmak, avoid posting code in comments that is this large, it is very difficult to read.  Instead edit your question so we can more easily see it.

Comment: I tried to send you whole program. Sorry for the mess.

Comment: Please post **real code** in a minimal example that demonstrates the problem. *Do not retype, but copy-paste from a compilable program.*

Answer (score 11):

```
for(editA.i; editA.i<6; editA.i++)  // Loop 1 
{ 
    for(editB.j=0; editB.j<6; editB.j++)    // Loop 2 
    { 
        if(editA.A[editA.i] == editB.B[editB.j])  // if this statment works  I want to go back to "Loop 1"
        {
            sum+= abs(editA.i - editB.j); 
            break ;
        }

        else 
            sum+= 1000; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: That's how I used break, but it does not go back to Loop 1.
    
    for(editA.i; editA.i<6; editA.i++)
    {
    for(editB.j=0; editB.j<6; editB.j++)
    {
    if(editA.A[editA.i] == editB.B[editB.j])
    {
     sum+= abs(editA.i - editB.j);
     break;
     
    }
    else
     sum+= 1000;
   }
  }

Comment: What you are saying does not make sense.  When you use break, that causes the code to immediately leave the inner for-loop.  Then code execution begins again at the end of the inner for-loop.  Then the outer for-loop is executed again.

Comment: The main statement is this: `"I want to go back to Loop 1, if the if-statement is successful. I need the program not to add a 1000, if the if-statement succeeds."` The `sum+= abs(editA.i - editB.j);` was already after `if` so I am assuming he wanted to do that, and then go back to loop 1, so start the loop 2 over, since he put `editB.j=0` as the first argument.

Comment: @Grzegorz yes you got me. I wanted to do it as you say

Comment: A ---> AB, DH, FJ, SA(document)
B ---> AB, FJ, CD, SA (category)

Here is an example what I wanted to do. I want to compare this two string to get the distance measure. Here the sum should give 2001 according to my program.

Comment: This should work.. why do you think it does not work? what are is the exact statement that is executing after the break that you do not want. Try to step through the program and see where it is going.

Answer (score 1):

I would add a break statement to the 'if statement' if you only wish to escape from the inner loop. If you want to escape both loops completely, you should use a return statement instead.

Answer (score 1):

Grzegorz's answer is correct, however, your requirement might be different.

Is this what you want?

```
for(editA.i; editA.i<6; editA.i++)  // Loop 1
{
    bool found = false;
    for(editB.j=0; editB.j<6; editB.j++)    // Loop 2
    {
        if(editA.A[editA.i] == editB.B[editB.j]) {  
           sum+= abs(editA.i - editB.j);
           found = true;
           break; 

       }

    }
    if ( !found ) {
        sum += 1000;
    }
}
```

Comment: @SermetCakmak, in the future you should include examples of exactly what you want and what it is you are currently getting.  If you had given use the numbers that your program was generating, along with the number you had desired, it would be a lot easier to determine what was wrong.  Otherwise we have to play a guessing game with your code and your vague responses to figure out what is wrong.

Comment: I have one more question related to this segment of code. I need to show you the real codes. This one was an example what I wanted do. How can I contact with you?